# Remove xsi nil through regex

Tags: c#, .net, xml, regex

I have a third party component that produce serialized xml and stored procedure that parse xml and insert values into tables.

I am having trouble with xsi nil handled in the component and sql stored procedure. I don't have control to change either the component or the stored procedure. So the IsNullable attribute on the property solution and  not xsi=true on the procedure solution doesn't help me.

I am trying to handle this using regex.

```
.*xsi\:nil\=\"true\" \/\>
```

The above regex match works perfect for the below input

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<prop1>
    <prop11>abc</prop11>
    <prop12 xsi:nil="true" />
    <prop13>def</prop13>
</prop1>
</Root>
```

But not for this input

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><prop1><prop11>abc</prop11><prop12 xsi:nil="true" /><prop13>def</prop13></prop1></Root>
```

Desired output is

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<prop1>
    <prop11>abc</prop11>
    <prop13>def</prop13>
</prop1>
</Root>
```

Update:
The property name and the level is only known at run time. Please refer a different xml below

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<pa>
    <paa>abc</paa>
    <pab xsi:nil="true" />
    <pac>def</pac>
            <pad>
               <pada>val1</pada>
               <padb xsi:nil="true" />
               <padc>
                     <padca>vala</padca>
                     <padcb xsi:nil="true" />
               </padc>
            <pad>
</prop1>
</Root>
```

The desired output for the above xml is

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<pa>
    <paa>abc</paa>
    <pac>def</pac>
            <pad>
               <pada>val1</pada>
               <padc>
                     <padca>vala</padca>
               </padc>
            <pad>
</prop1>
</Root>
```

Could someone please help me

Thanks,

Esen

Comment: Are you replacing the value?  And with what?  IE, what is the desired result?

Comment: replacing it with empty string

Comment: Adjusted my answer to give you the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the XPath from this library: https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/

I get the XElements that have `xsi:nil=true` with:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
// or root = XElement.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> result = root.XPath("//*[@xsi:nil={0}]", true);
result.ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
root.Save(file);
// or xml = root.ToString();
```

I tested it with this XML:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <prop1>
    <prop10 xsi:nil="true" />
    <prop11>abc</prop11>
    <prop12 xsi:nil="true" />
    <prop13>def</prop13>
    <prop14 xsi:nil="true" />
    <prop15>def</prop15>
    <prop16 xsi:nil="true" />
  </prop1>
</Root>
```

And found all 4 XElements.  From there they are removed.

The resulting XML is:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <prop1>
    <prop11>abc</prop11>
    <prop13>def</prop13>
    <prop15>def</prop15>
  </prop1>
</Root>
```

If you don't care that the `xsi:nil` is true, and you just want all nodes with the `xsi:nil` attribute removed, you can frame the XPath like:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> result = root.XPath("//*[@xsi:nil]");
```

Comment: Thanks chuck, is it possible to make it generic. Because the property name is unknown to me. And the level of property that hold null value is also unknown. Please refer my second example

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq to XML

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

        var f = XDocument.Load("c:\\01.xml");
        var xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        var nills = from n in f.Root.Elements("prop1").Elements()
                    where n.Attribute(xsi + "nil") != null
                    select n;

        nills.ToList().ForEach(x => x.RemoveAttributes());

        f.Save("c:\\011.xml");
```

This produced the following result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <prop1>
    <prop11>abc</prop11>
    <prop12 />
    <prop13>def</prop13>
  </prop1>
</Root>
```